# Let user write and run ruby code?

Tags: ruby

I am in the process of creating a little codewriting training game for giggles. The game shall be in ruby, and I want the user to write code and then let the game look at it and what the code returns, a little like in _why's hackety (but from a cli).

I can't find a way to do this, do you know how?

Comment: @Michael - beat me to it. fromhet, please don't use foul language here; we try and keep things professional and adult, and some people find profanity offensive. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) can help you better understand how to ask questions here, and what conduct is acceptable. Thanks.

Comment: YOu may take a look to the [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/)

Comment: Oh, I'm very sorry. It won't happen again!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892968/safe-execution-in-ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-eval), which interprets a String as ruby code. If you're wondering how to write the text editor portion, that is more difficult (and beyond the scope of this website). The simplest solution would be use to readline in the standard library, which lets you create an IRB-like prompt.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to gets the users code into a variable and then eval(variable)?

Comment: Yes, that would be a good way to do it. Readline would be one method of getting the user's code into a variable.